# InApp Purchase in Ionic 3 - How do I implement a payment between users?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I would like to implement a system in my app that allows one user to buy a digital product from another user. See this as an event ticket reservation system. The organizer is the seller and the final user is the buyer.

I would take a little fee to make it profitable.

Are those kind of payment subject to 30% commission from Google?

Do you know a secure system (PayPal maybe?) that could help me to set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple or Android in app purchases can be only used in conjunction with use cases defined by developer agreement.

All purchasing using an app is subject to the 30% fee, except for very specific use cases (like newspaper media subscription, etc.).

User-to-user real money transfer is a very tricky concept (as it basically allows funds transfer between individuals and tax and other authorities would want to control that) from both a legal and accounting points of view.

Unless you have serious business and you are willing to spent considerable resources to validate all nuances it is generally not a good easy idea to go with for an independent developer.

You can check [Stripe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripe_(company)) Connect as the closest offering for web projects: https://stripe.com/connect

But also see their limitations section to see if it is even suitable.